# ORMError NO_SUPPORT: Connection protocol not supported - have you installed the database driver for postgres?

Tags: node.js, node-orm2

I'm trying to deploy a nodejs application on ubuntu 13.10. I have tested it on my local mac( working good).

But when I try to run it on my ubuntu server, i got this:

```
[ORMError NO_SUPPORT: Connection protocol not supported - have you installed the database driver for postgres?]
at Object.exports.connect (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/orm/lib/ORM.js:138:21)
at Object.module.exports (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/orm/lib/Express.js:12:6)
at Object.exports.express (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/orm/lib/ORM.js:39:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/www/sher/nodejs/app.js:30:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

**FYI:**

I installed `npm install pg` after i got this error, but didn't work.

I also instadded postgresql9.1 with `sudo apt-get install build-essential postgresql-9.1 postgresql-server-dev-9.1 libxml2-dev libproj-dev libjson0-dev xsltproc docbook-xsl docbook-mathml`.

Anyone can suggest any idea whats going on here?

Thank you!

```
{
  "name": "nodejs",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
},
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.2.0",
    "static-favicon": "~1.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "debug": "~0.7.4",
    "jade": "~1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reinstalled all packages and modules again one by one. Seems fixed the problem.

Comment: I had this issue with all projects I have that use orm that was caused when upgrading node versions between 6/7/8 on the same system. Reinstalling all packages in each project resolved it - assume there is some binary level compatibility issue there, thanks for the suggestion.